# how add (baseurl /controller/action) for e.g www.domainname.com/testController/testAction as default value for magneto admin store config field

Tags: php, magento

I have make a custom module for magneto .I want set  some default value  means (baseurl/controller/action)   in admin configuration field. a base URL means domain name where magneto installed so default value like in this way  www.domain.com/controller/action . I have try in following way but it not working .

Code in system.xml file  :-

```
<loyaltyauthurl translate="label">
   <label> Authentication URL</label>
   <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
   <sort_order>20</sort_order>
   <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
   <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
   <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
   <depends>
      <enable>1</enable>
      <enableLoyalty>1</enableLoyalty>
   </depends>
</loyaltyauthurl>
```

Code in config.xml file :-

```
<general>
    <loyaltyauthurl>{{base_url}}</loyaltyauthurl>
</general>
```

Custom module Configuration screen :-

[image]

Comment: can you describe how it's not working?

Comment: in above image "loyalty authentication URL " show the value as  {{ base_url }}  . instated of I want show  “host name/mycontroller/action” for e.g  http://localhost/magento/test/test .

Comment: You should edit and update the actual question